# Custom validation for file size in rails before being uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

in my form i have

```
<%= label_tag("file", "Attachment:") %><%= file_field_tag "uploadfile" %>
```

In my model i would like to write this

```
validate :validates_uploadfile

def validates_uploadfile(file)
    max_size = 2048
    errors.add(:uploadfile, "File size exceeds limitation") if file.size > max_size
end
```

In my controller can i call something like this

```
validates_upload_file(params[:uploadfile])
```

**Is there a way to validate a file upload before being uploaded(not by using javascript or by looking at the file extension)**
Thanks for the help

**UPD**

```
validate :uploadfile_validation, :if => "uploadfile?"

def uploadfile_validation
    errors[:uploadfile] << "should be less than 1MB" if uploadfile.size > 1.megabytes
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's my code for size validations (I use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for uploads).

```
  validate :picture_size_validation, :if => "picture?"  

  def picture_size_validation
    errors[:picture] << "should be less than 1MB" if picture.size > 1.megabytes
  end
```

Cheers.

Comment: hi, i have edited my code above, however i get an error undefined local variable or method `uploadfile', any thoughts. iam not using carrierwave or paperclip, i am uploading directly to s3.

Comment: Try something like `"!uploadfile.blank?"` instead of `"uploadfile?"` - I think `picture?` is a method defined by CarrierWave

Comment: thanks for the help, i finally installed carrierwave, as things were not working out, after some time i got the above code snippet to work, thanks again.

Comment: Does this size of the file get checked before or after the file is uploaded?

Comment: Before uploading. I just checked right now because I had a doubt but it works fine.

Comment: Rails 5: `..., if: -> { picture }`

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
validates_size_of :picture, maximum: 1.megabytes, message: "should be less than 1MB"
```

Comment: This works, but not before upload. File will be uploaded into the cache

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, then all those methods above check the file size once its been uploaded ( and maybe even processed ) but what happens if I choose a 1GB file in file input field for pictures considering that javascript validation is absent or javascript is just disabled? It probablt gets uploaded, taking a lot of time just to tell ya that its too big, that just aint right. I am a newbie so I might be wrong about something ...

Comment: yep, `client_max_body_size 5M`

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov So, just to make sure. If I write absolutely no code any files larger than 5 MB wont upload?

Comment: @MCB correct, check this link http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: I'd stay away from adding validation within a web server configuration file