# how to validate the filsize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

please help solve the problem.

I use gem paperclip and documentation:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master#validations

I implemented upload files. it works. Now I need to add validation rules. I do the following:
model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :video, presence: true

  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :video, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

validates_attachment :video, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpeg" },
  :size => { :in => 0..200.kilobytes }  
end
```

controller:

```
def create 
  @video = Video.new(video_params)   

  if @video.save
    flash[:success] = :video_created
    redirect_to @video
  else
    flash.now[:error] = :user_not_created
    render 'new'
  end
end

def video_params
  params.require(:video).permit(:title, :video)
end
```

as a result of getting into the console the following error message:

```
Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-22 17:18:22 +0300
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wIpQDmh1irqKjGycTpfl/J0UVKGvv4ptmL9l1xHyfAa0Q/WP/jCOFlLWf4nR3wKtjUB+b7TVbpG5XfYBP/oA9Q==", "video"=>{"title"=>"yyy", "video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f140184ff00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150722-29111-yn1mqv.jpg>, @original_filename="BTWzqHonWRs.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[video]\"; filename=\"BTWzqHonWRs.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Video"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/8924685e4bfe6957f64963710295779820150722-29111-wl5fmt.jpg'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (comparison of String with 204800 failed):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:40:in `create'
```

on screen displays the following error message:

```
ArgumentError in VideosController#create
comparison of String with 204800 failed
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
  validate :file_size_validation, :if => "video?"  

  def file_size_validation
    errors[:video] << "should be less than 2MB" if video.size > 2.megabytes
  end
```

For more information see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440943/custom-validation-for-file-size-in-rails-before-being-uploaded).

Answer (score 0):

```
 validate :file_size_validation, :if => "video?"  

  def file_size_validation
    errors[:video] << "should be less than 2MB" if video.size.to_i > 1.kilobytes
  end
```